# How to build a network-coding based wireless sensor network in Omnet with INET

Tags: c++, networking, network-programming, omnet++, inet

[Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QR4yP.png)

I want to build a basic x topology wireless network to test the network-coding in Omnet with INET. The basic structure of this network is shown in the Figure 1. There
are two sources SA and SB, two destinations DA and DB, and one relay R in this topology. SA, R and DB are within each other’s broadcast range, and SB, R and DA are within each other’s broadcast range. In a certain time period, two groups of packets X = {x1, x2, …, X|x|} from SA to DA and Y = {y1, y2, …, Y|y|} from SB to DB are received by R. So R can encode X and Y together before forwarding them.

*(1) Overhearing:* Every node should work in a promiscuous mode. So the destinations DA and DB can overhear packets transmitted from SA and SB to R respectively. Let Ox and Oy be the overheard packets from X and Y by DB and DA respectively.At the destinations, all the overheard packets are the native packets and can be used to decode the coded packets.

*(2) Encoding:* When relay R receives the native packets X and Y, it encodes these packets together and broadcasts the coded packets simultaneously to receivers DA and DB. The encode operation is merely a simple random linear combination of native packets as Z1=ga1*X1+gb1*Y1, where the ga1 and gb1 are the coefficients randomly selected from a q-order Galois field GF(q). And Z1 is the coded packet. The coefficients will be included in the header of the coded packets.

*(3) Decoding:* DA will decode all packets in X and Y using the received coded packets Z1 together with the overheardpackets OY which is Y1 by using Gaussian Elimination. Similarly, DB will do the same to DA.

@Jerzy D.

Comment: I have a few doubts: **1.** Which standard of radio transmission are you intend to use? **2.** Assume that R has received a packet from SA. How long it should wait for packet from SB? Are the sources SA and SB synchronized? **3.** Let's packet X1 contain 4 bytes: 0x10, 0xFF, 0x38, 0x88 and ga1 = 3. How ga1*X1 should be calculated - as operation of multiplying 8bit number by ga1? And what if overflow occurs? **4.** How do you want add two packets - by adding values or by appending one packet to the end of second packet?

Comment: Hi Jerzy, I find this X structure is hard to explain what I want to get. I will post another structure  and also answer your doubts in the new question. I will tell you the name of question when I finish it.

Comment: The question name is How to build a network-coding based Converge-Cast wireless sensor network in Omnet with INET.